# Bootstraps changes font weight of my nav when clicked on field

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I downloaded html5 boilerplate with bootstrap and when I click on the field in the nav, it changes the font weight from bold to light.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your field gets .active class when you click on it, and font-weight settings in that class.

Comment: It doesn't add an active class

Comment: Check nav a element with [CSS Pseudo classes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp). Somewhere it changes from font-weight from bold to light, or from 700 to 300.